# Как разрешить ввод текста в input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы для цифр работала маска, а буквы печатались без маски?

```js
function mask(phone) {
    var code = '',
    find = /\+7/;
    code = '';
    find = /\+7/;
    phone.addEventListener('focus', function () {
        phone.value = code + " " + phone.value.replace(code + ' ', '');
    });
    phone.addEventListener('input', function () {
        var val = phone.value.replace(find, ''),
        res = code + " ";
       // val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
          val = val.replace(/[^0-9,a-zA-Z]/g, '');
    
          if (res = val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')){
              input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
          };

        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            res += i === 0 ? ' (' : '';
            res += i == 3 ? ') ' : '';
            res += i == 6 || i == 6 ? '-' : '';
            if (i == 10) break;
                res += val[i];
        };
        phone.value = res;
    });
    phone.addEventListener('blur', function () {
        var val = phone.value.replace(find, '');
        val = val.trim();
        if (!val) phone.value = null;
    });
};
function maskInput(doc) {
    var phone = doc.querySelectorAll('input[id="userName"]');
    if (phone) {
        var i = phone.length;
        while (i--) {
            mask(phone[i]);
        }
    }
};
maskInput(document);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="autocomplete" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: а зачем один и тот же инпут использовать для ввода имени и для ввода телефона?

Comment: Очень нужно именно так

Comment: Нет, так не нужно. Это неправильно

Comment: Ну очень очень надо, пусть не правильно.

Comment: Может есть другой код для таких целей?

Comment: Да есть - использовать разные инпуты

Comment: Надо в одном. Многие так пользуются. Наверное там надо условие как-то сделать.

Comment: Так делают только извращенцы. Или вы сами это себе в голове придумали.

Comment: Да почему. Форма входа по номеру или по имени в одном и том же поле. Есть пример такой реализации, но он мало чем поможет

Comment: Ага, а взглянуть в html код  и о ужас, там два поля будет, просто одно скрывается, другое показывается.

Comment: Нет, input один. Там когда нажимаешь первый символ цифру, то у input меняется на `type="tel"`, а по умолчанию стоит `type="text"`

Comment: Добавил код. Вот сейчас работает как надо, только ошибку выдаёт